# Fix caulk along inground vinyl pool liner and plastic seat

Tags: pool

I converted my inground pool to salt a month ago. Chemicals have been balanced and it’s great. About two weeks ago I noticed the water level going down more than usual.
I inspected the vinyl for any tears and found nothing. But I did notice today the caulk where the vinyl liner meets the walk in steps and the “seat” looks separated and in one spot the caulk pulled away.
Is this bc of the saltwater or is it just old caulk.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is old calking salt water is really hard on metals but I have not seen problems with salt water systems and the seals or calking, I have had god luck with salt water only 1 failed wire loop but that was after 7-8 years.